# Multi value filter using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, where-clause

I have a candidate table. Within that, I have a column named skills. It's storing multiple values with a delimiter. Now I want to create a search filter including skills. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By redesigning your table to adhere to normalisation conventions so that you can use the features of your RDBMS! Why are you storing skills in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, one option uses `find_in_set()`:

```
select * from candidates where find_in_set(?, skills)
```

`?` represents the skill that you search for.

That said, a far better option would be to normalize your schema. You should not be storing multiple values in a single column. Instead, you should have a separate table to store the relationships between candidates and skills, with each candidate/skill tuple on a separate row.

Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)